Counting the number of terms of $\left(x + \frac1x + y + \frac1y\right)^{14}$

Find the number of distinct terms in
$$\left(x + \frac1x + y + \frac1y\right)^{14}$$

The general term can be written as $x^{a-b} y^{c-d}$, and $a+b+c+d=14$. I tried to solve the number of solutions, but then I realised that for certain different pair $(a, b, c, d)$, there can be same values of $a-b$ and $c-d$ (example $(3,2,5,4)$ and $(5,4,3,2)$), which further complicated my approach.
Any better approach?

Hint : Note that $x+1/x+y+1/y=(x+y)(1+xy)/xy$

The number of terms in $\left(x + \frac1x + y + \frac1y\right)^{n}$ for $n=0,1,2,3$ suggests a pattern.  Then consider which and how many possible powers of $x$ can multiply $y^k$ for $-n \le k \le n$

This is the generating function for lattice paths of length $14$ from the origin $(0,0)$, where each step moves right ($x)$, left ($1/x$), up $(y)$, or down ($1/y$).  The reachable points are clearly those in the diamond with corners $(\pm 14,0)$ and $(0,\pm 14)$.  This is a square with $(14+1)^2$ lattice points.  More generally, for power $n$ instead of $14$, the square has $(n+1)^2$ lattice points.

Let me put down my hint from the comments as an answer (and I will make it community wiki). There will be a second, more direct hint in the spoilers.
Hint: Note that $$(x+1/x+y+1/y)=\frac{(x+y)(1+xy)}{xy}$$

 Next hint : The $xy$ factor in the denominator is inconsequential. And $(a+b)^n$ has $n+1$ distinct terms.


This is not a mathematical proof but rather a brute force method that at least suggests an answer.  Using Mathematica to expand on @Henry 's comment:
t = Table[Length[List @@ ((x + 1/x + y + 1/y)^i // Expand)], {i, 1, 20}]
(* {4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441} *)
FindSequenceFunction[t, n] // FullSimplify
(* (n + 1)^2 *)

